# App.Config file - Referencing an Assembly Error

Tags: .net, configuration, .net-assembly

I have a .net assembly(UserAppDetails) referenced by another .net assembly(ClientDetails) in a WinForms application.

The WinForms application calls ClientDetails, which in turn calls UserAppDetails.

However, I get the below error.

```
An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for applicationSettings/UserAppDetails.Properties.Settings: Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

In the app.config, I have added the below to both the ClientDetails app.config and the WinForm app.config...

```
<section name="UserAppDetails.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
```

All assemblies and WinForm app are version 3.5
Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: you started a bounty at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162732/ssis-2012-vs-isbroken-on-derived-column with `250 rep` and it is ending and you didn't logged in at dba.stackexchange till now, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to "Version=2.0.0.0" - you want to use .NET Framework 3.5 whose underlying runtime is actually 2.0!